# How to select stored procedure output parameters as a table in oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper, output-parameter

I have a procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE proc
(
  p1 IN varchar2,
  p2 IN varchar2,
  p3 OUT varchar2
) AS
BEGIN
 p3:= p1 || ' ' || p2
END proc
```

I call it by

```
Declare
  P3 varchar(50);
Begin
 proc('foo', 'bar', P3)
END;
```

I can print out the value of P3 using

```
Dbms_Output.Put_line('P3: ' || P3)
```

But I need to get the result as a table I can select from.
Best way I can think of is

```
Declare
  P3 varchar(50);
Begin
 proc('foo', 'bar', P3)
END;
SELECT &&P3 from dual;
```

But that gives me an error

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 5, column 12:
PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
ORA-06550: line 5, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL statement ignored
06550. 00000 - "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause: Usually a PL/SQL compilatiopn error.
*Action:
```

Is there some way of selecting the value of a parameter as a column/row value?

I need this all done inside the single sql query because I need to executed it from another server via linked server.

I don't have permission to create any other stored procedures, functions or tables on the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me, the most straightforward option is to create a function - it is supposed to *return a value*:

```
create or replace function proc (p1 IN varchar2, p2 IN varchar2)
  return varchar2
AS
BEGIN
  return p1 || ' ' || p2;
END proc;
```

Then you'd call it as e.g.

```
select proc('a', 'b') from dual;
```

---

Saying that you "don't have permission to create ... functions" - well, if you are granted to create a PROCEDURE, then you are also granted to create a FUNCTION. It is the same privilege.

---

If you can only use procedures that are already created, then:

```
SQL> create or replace PROCEDURE proc
  2  (
  3    p1 IN varchar2,
  4    p2 IN varchar2,
  5    p3 OUT varchar2
  6  ) AS
  7  BEGIN
  8    p3:= p1 || ' ' || p2;
  9  END ;
 10  /

Procedure created.

SQL> var result varchar2(20)
SQL>
SQL> exec proc('a', 'b', :result);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :result

RESULT
--------------------------------
a b
    
SQL> select :result from dual;

:RESULT
--------------------------------
a b

SQL>
```

Comment: Like I said I don't have permission to create or modify any stored procedures or functions. The function is created by the owner of the server and all I've got is a log in with select permission.

Comment: Aha; so you can only use what's already been created. OK; I added some more code into the answer, have a look.

Comment: If I add ```select :result from dual;``` it asks me to enter binds for ```result``` and then just selects the value I enter instead of the value the procedure returns.

Comment: Disable that feature in a tool you use (for this particular task). Reenable it later.

Comment: Would you by any chance happen to know how to do that? I'm using oracle sql developer 20.4.0.379.2205 x64.

Comment: In SQL Developer, select ("paint" it blue) the SELECT statement and run it **as script** (F5 keyboard shortcut).

Comment: Well that works. But this gives me the result as a script output and not as a query result and I still won't be able to select it via my linked server.

Comment: Can you switch to SQL*Plus, then? I don't know what else to do in SQL Developer as you're quite "restricted" by privileges you have.

Comment: Ok in SQL*Plus your solution works perfectly. Thank you for all your help and all the time you spent on this question. I'm completely new to oracle.

Answer (score 4):

If you're on Oracle 12c onwards you can use [`WITH FUNCTION`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABJCBCC) feature added to that version. With it you can wrap your procedure into PL/SQL block of locally defined function and use this function within `SELECT`. No `CREATE PROCEDURE` needed for this to work.

> ```
> create procedure proc (
>   p1 in int,
>   p2 in int,
>   pout out int
> )
> as
> begin
>   pout := p1 + p2;
> end;
> /
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> with function f(
>   p1 in int,
>   p2 in int
> ) return int
> as
>   pout int;
> begin
>   proc(p1, p2, pout);
>   return (pout);
> end;
>
> select f(1,2)
> from dual
> ```
>
> ```
> | F(1,2) |
> | -----: |
> |      3 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c0c4e0253c4d5a71a63620c2522ce01e)*

Comment: That does indeed do exactly what I need. Thank you.